# Layout is not working

Tags: java, android, performance, android-layout, user-interface

I am creating different layouts for different screensizes using the `layout-sw<>dp` qualifier, but for some reason, it is not working. I have the following layouts:[image]

I made a special sw320dp directory so that it looks nice on one of my test devices which was 569 dp x 320 dp. Then, for my [LG-G3](https://design.google.com/devices/), which is 480 dp x 853 dp, I made the `layout-sw480dp` folder.

**However, the 320dp layout is showing on both phones, including my LG G3.**

Am I doing something wrong? Shouldn't the 480dp layout show on my LG G3?  Please let me know.

Ruchir

Comment: What is your project target android version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#NewQualifiers) tells to consider actual sizes that are available to your activity's window when choosing qualifiers

> The smallestWidth of a device takes into account screen decorations
>   and system UI. For example, if the device has some persistent UI
>   elements on the screen that account for space along the axis of the
>   smallestWidth, the system declares the smallestWidth to be smaller
>   than the actual screen size, because those are screen pixels not
>   available for your UI.

so ensure you have at least 480dp available to your screen and it is not partially taken up by any system UI/ screen decoration.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, but the LG G3 doesn't have any persistent on screen decorations that I know of. Even if so, I got the number 480 dp from the link I provided in my question, Google's official device dimensions. What am I doing wrong? Please let me know.

Comment: Value provided in the link will I guess provide you real screen size in dp. Try to log actual screen size in dp programatically for your current activity. See if size returned from `getRealMetrics` and `getMetrics` differ and if they do, where is that space consumed

Comment: You are right, programmatically, the width is 360dp, and it works then! I have accepted and liked your answer, but I have one more more question. Why did the link say the LG G3 has a width of 480dp x 853 dp, when in reality it is 360dp x 640dp when I checked programmatically? Please let me know.

Comment: if difference is not due to system UI or screen decoration then I suppose you should only rely on actual values returned by device as models might change resolution in newer versions and links might not reflect those changes